# How to save DataTable as an Excel file (not csv) and then open it?

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-office, office-interop, xls

I use this code to open `DataTable` in Excel. It's a wpf application.

```
      excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
      wb = excel.Workbooks.Add();
      ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Sheets.Add();
      for (var i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++) {
        ws.Range["A1"].Offset[0, i].Value = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {
        ws.Range["A2"].Offset[i].Resize[1, dt.Columns.Count].Value = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray;
      }

      excel.Visible = true;
      wb.Activate();
```

**But I want first to save a file as a  `xls` file** (not csv) and then open it in Excel. Or at least open it in Excel saved -- meaning, when I open it, it's already written on a disk. Now the code above just opens Excel with no file name -- the data isn't saved on the disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save an Excel workbook, use the [Workbook.SaveAs method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx). Insert this line just before the wb.Activate line.

```
wb.SaveAs("C:\Example\Example.xls", xlExcel8)
```

Comment: thanks, but it says "the format and extenstion don't much" when I'm opening it again. Maybe you know the reason?

Comment: Oops, yea you need to tell Excel to save it in the Excel 97-2003 format rather than the CSV format. I edited my answer.

Comment: xlExcel8 is an [XlFileFormat enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx) that is presented as the FileFormat argument to the SaveAs method. The versions of Excel from 1997-2003 all used the Excel 8.0 file format, hence the name xlExcel8.